# URL maskin in React Router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

everyone

i have case, i need masking my ugly url to good url for seo purpose, because in SEO, ugly url will duplicate, example case:

when user go to `myweb.com/sales` it direct to `myweb.com/products?product_search%5Bpage%5D=1`, but url in browser still `myweb.com/sales`

i have tried use `<Redirect />` but it's not working, i mean, url in browser change to ugly url

how i solved this in react js ?

Thx

Comment: Why the redirect? You should be fixing the problem from the root, which is why it lands to `?product_search` in the first place. React can handle friend-urls in a very simple way: `<Route path="/user/:userId" component={User}/>`, so that is where you should be looking at.

Comment: Hi @zurfyx, i have that route too, but i need is create another landing page which is in `myweb.com/sales` but same as `myweb.com/products?product_search%5Bpage%5D=1`